# Change display of sibling by his brother children count

Tags: css

Hi i have the following html

```
<div>
    <div class='brother1'>
      HELLO
       <div class='item'>One</div>
       <div class='item'>Two</div>
       <div class='item'>Three</div>
       <div class='item'>Seven</div>
    </div>

    <div class='brother2 button'>
        BUTTON
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to set button to be invisible if the amount of items(One,Two,Three...) is bigger that 3.
But if the amount is less then 3 i want the button to be visible.

Is this possible using **css only?**

If this is not possible how would you change the html structure to achieve the same behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: No it is not possible with css.

Comment: No.............

Comment: @Huelfe If this is not possible how would you change the html structure to achieve the same behavior?

Comment: Have a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/copLuh45/). If you remove `Seven` and `Eight` you will get your wanted result.

Comment: For this you would need both `:nth-of-class()` and `:has()` selectors which doesn't exist in css so i think closest you can get is something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2047/ which is not what you are looking for because you have to change html structure and also it fails if there is some other elements other then `.item`